# Unable to delete a user from a Linux CentOS 6.3 machine, what can be done?

Tags: centos6, user-accounts, passwd

When I try deleting my user (from a root shell) it says `userdel: cannot remove entry 'itaig' from /etc/passwd`
The user isn't even displayed on `/etc/passwd`.

```
[root@ab2c1 ~]# su - itaig
su: warning: cannot change directory to /home/itaig: No such file or directory
-bash-4.1$ exit
logout
[root@ab2c1 ~]# mkdir /home/itaig
[root@ab2c1 ~]# chown itaig.itaig /home/itaig/
[root@ab2c1 ~]# grep itaig /etc/passwd
[root@ab2c1 ~]# grep itaig /etc/shadow
[root@ab2c1 ~]# userdel -rf itaig
userdel: cannot remove entry 'itaig' from /etc/passwd
[root@ab2c1 ~]#
```

I have the exact same problem in other servers as well but i can't find a common ground between them:

```
[root@amad ~]# userdel itaig
userdel: cannot remove entry 'itaig' from /etc/passwd
[root@amad ~]# useradd itaig
useradd: user 'itaig' already exists
[root@amad ~]#
```

How come my user is not displayed in /etc/passwd but still exists on the system?
I've checked `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and found no problem there...
What can be done in order to fix this issue?

Edit:
The output of `strace userdel itaig` can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/FFkcQ3fj

And the output of `strace useradd itaig`:
http://pastebin.com/twRQ7ps0

Second Edit: It seems that if I manually add my user to `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/group` I am then able to delete the user using the command `userdel itaig` , but even then I'm unable to re-create the user as I get an error that the user already exists. 
Any help would be appreciated!

```
[root@ab2c1 ~]# userdel itaig
[root@ab2c1 ~]# useradd itaig
useradd: user 'itaig' already exists
[root@ab2c1 ~]# userdel itaig
userdel: cannot remove entry 'itaig' from /etc/passwd
[root@ab2c1 ~]# grep itaig /etc/passwd
[root@ab2c1 ~]# grep itaig /etc/group
[root@ab2c1 ~]# grep itaig /etc/shadow
[root@ab2c1 ~]# id itaig
uid=509(itaig) gid=510(itaig) groups=510(itaig)
[root@ab2c1 ~]#
```

Contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
passwd:     files   nis
shadow:     files   nis
group:      files   nis
#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      files nis dns
bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files
netgroup:   nisplus
publickey:  nisplus
automount:  files nisplus
aliases:    files nisplus
```

I wonder where the information of the `id` command comes from:

```
[root@ab2c1 ~]# grep itaig /etc/passwd
[root@ab2c1 ~]# grep itaig /etc/shadow
[root@ab2c1 ~]# grep itaig /etc/group
[root@ab2c1 ~]# id itaig
uid=509(itaig) gid=510(itaig) groups=510(itaig)
[root@ab2c1 ~]#
```

Comment: What do `getent passwd itaig` and `getent shadow itaig` say?

Comment: Do you have LDAP authentication configured on this machine? Or some other form of remote directory authentication?

Comment: Etan: the getent password shows me a line like the ones in /etc/passwd
and the getent shadow give me a fresh prompt line without and output

Comment: John: No, only linux security

Comment: you could try to run strace userdel itaig

Comment: Or more likely, `strace useradd itaig`.  That should help indicate where/how useradd thinks the user exists.

Comment: Have you tried removing the user using vipw? Does it work?

Comment: My user is not shown there as well...

Comment: and what about lsof -u itaig ?

Comment: Alex_hha: Nothing, I get a new prompt.

Comment: Please show the contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: Done, edited question.

Comment: You say you did this from a root shell. Did you originally login as root, or did you log in as itaig and then use sudo to open a root shell?

Comment: I logged on initially with root but just to be on the safe side I ran `# pkill -KILL -u itaig` but to no avail.

Comment: What about name service caching daemons such as nscd or sssd? Try temporarily stopping, or at least restarting, these services after you have removed the user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read up on and try the `pwconv`, `pwunconv` and `pwck` commands to get your passwd and shadow files in sync again.  Then try to use your `userdel`.

Also, is there a reason that you are leaving nis and nisplus defined in your /etc/nsswitch.conf file?  I have seen unnecessary naming services cause lag in various functionality due to the fact that they are performing lookups to services that aren't implemented in your environment.  I would also clear all of those out to see if you see any improvement in your `userdel` issue.

Comment: It seems like I wasn't able to delete the user because it was added on the NIS server... Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar issue where the user existed on a SSS server which appears to relate to LDAP. Temporarily removing sss from `/etc/nsswitch.conf` was the solution for me.

Comment: 'Read up on' isn't an answer.

Comment: Just teaching a person to fish.

Comment: The purpose of stackoverflow/serverfault isn't to teach people how to fish, it's to provide useful answers to questions.